# Java regex except some charcaters

Tags: java, regex

In the following code, I have a small set of data; dates and prices. However, I want to just display the prices:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        String[] data = new String[4];
        data[0]="Dec 10, 2015";
        data[1]="116.04";
        data[2]="Dec 9, 2015";
        data[3]="46,361,357";


        for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++){
            String qq = "\\d+.[^\\s]\\d*.\\d+";
            Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile(qq);
            Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(data[i]);

            while(m2.find()){
                System.out.println(m2.group());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
10, 2015
116.04
46,361,357
```

As you can see, it doesn't display `Dec 9` which is what I want but displays `Dec 10`. Can someone help me solving this problem? Please note that I am not allowed to use any library in this work. It is a regex work only.

Comment: Note: To match `.` literally, you need to escape it otherwise it'll match any character that is not newline

Comment: "However, I want to just explain the prices:" what does that mean? "regex will exclude the spaces which is after , in the dates" oh, I thought we were talking about prices? "It works fine with Dec 9" what did work fine?

Comment: @Aaron I want to display the prices only. The regex displays the prices but it also displays `10,2015` which must not be displayed. My question how can I modify the regex so that it doesn't the dates?

Comment: Check [this demo](http://ideone.com/3cMI4C). It outputs only the strings that are numbers (with `,` as a digit grouping symbol and a `.` as a decimal separator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regex will match strings that start and end with a digit and can contain any number of `.` and `,`:

```
^\d[\d.,]+\d$
```

See [a demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/0e6epahwghDCDnq7).

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 1):

A good definition for your prices would be the following :

```
^\\d+([.,]\\d+)*$
```

The main improvment compared to yours is that I make sure I match the whole string by encasing the regex in `^...$`.

Also I'm not sure using regexps here is such a good idea. A try/catch on Integer.parseInt would have had the same result.